# I would like to have a background-image with a 'fade out effect'. CSS3

Tags: html, css, gradient

Is it possible to achieve fade out transparent effect on an image from the center of an image to the left of the image

I have tried the below and i get no results

```
#content {
display: block;
width: 960px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 48px;
background-image: url(../images/feature-image-wild-horse.jpg),    -moz-linear-gradient(left, #444444, #999999); /* FF3.6+ */
overflow: hidden;
```

}

Comment: Hmm no if i wanted to do that. I would just do the image as a PNG, I want to learn how to use the new CSS3 functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use a blurred inset box shadow (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/box-shadow):
http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/NkHdh/4/

```
#content {
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/350/350);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 70px 0px 50px -10px white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 70px 0px 50px -10px white;
     box-shadow:inset 70px 0px 50px -10px white;
}
```

---

If you want to use a gradient, you can use `:before` to get the gradient to overlay the background image, otherwise the gradient won't be seen.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/brqcu/2/

```
#content {
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/350/350);
}

#content:before {
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff', GradientType=1);
}
```