# Any ideas on how to add a transparent gradient to an image using css?

Tags: html, css, image

I was just wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to make the edges of an image transparent using css? I know it can be done to the background image and I use this method already on my site. What I am hoping to do is to make the sides and bottom of images contained in a slide show transparent so they fade into the background. I don't really want to have to do each image individually in Photoshop and was hoping to find a reliable method using css or even JavaScript. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Basically...no but your question is really not suitable in it's current form for Stack Overflow. Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893217/i-would-like-to-have-a-background-image-with-a-fade-out-effect-css3

Answer (score 0):

Yes... You can do this:

```css
.mask {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
}

.fader {display: inline-block;}
.fader img {position: relative; z-index: 1;}
```

```html
<div class="fader">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/" />
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```